# Why don't we have the "blatantly off-topic" option as a close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156498) seems to be closed as opinion-based, however the comments indicate that the question is not related to travel. I have the "cast close and reopen votes" privilege on TSE only, maybe I'm missing something, but I wonder why we don't have the following option as a close reason.

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with travel)

Comment: That option *only* shows up to users who don't have enough rep to vote to close and must flag.

Comment: @gparyani Is it the same on all SE sites or specific to TSE?

Comment: It's the same on all sites.

Comment: @gparyani Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When you choose to vote to close there is the option "Off-topic", and when you choose that you're given a number of pre-worded of topic close reasons.

If none of these options suit, there is also the "Other"  reason where you can enter your own reason such as "has nothing to do with travel"

[image]